# Concatenate url string with a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, url, concatenation

I want to use a link_to option and use a url which is variable.
So I wrote this :

```
<%= link_to "Panier", '/clients/#{liste.client_id}' %>
```

However I am redirected to the webpage `/clients` with the url `/clients/#{liste.client_id}`

Can anyone give me the solution and explain why it does not work ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use rails routes if possible.

```
<%= link_to "Panier", client_path(liste.client_id) %>
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine. I find it more safe isn't it ? More than concatenation ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's more safe as it doesn't rely on user input but I would always use the rails routes if possibl

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to:

```
<%= link_to "Panier", "/clients/#{liste.client_id}" %>
```

So Ruby performs interpolation. Otherwise it understands is *as-is*.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use `""` instead

```
<%= link_to "Panier", "/clients/#{liste.client_id}" %>
```

Hope that helps!